# Presenting unicode PUA area in java

Tags: java, unicode

I'm trying presenting unicode PUA area code into string to use as delimeter.

Here is my code snipping

```
String s = "CONN\u10FFFFHello World";
System.out.println(s);
```

I want to use `10FFFF` but in `System.out.println`, outputs `CONNჿFFHello World`. It seems only present `10FF` character...

How can I present PUA area code properly?

I'm developing on UTF-8 encoding.